# SELECT文の実行時間が長すぎる

Tags: sql, postgresql, database

## 説明

以下のようにテーブル"stock_bar"があります。
このテーブルには４０００万行以上のデータが入っています。

### stock_barテーブル定義

```
                        Table "public.stock_bar"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 symbol      | character(8)             |           | not null | 
 time_scale  | character(8)             |           | not null | 
 open        | numeric                  |           | not null | 
 high        | numeric                  |           | not null | 
 low         | numeric                  |           | not null | 
 close       | numeric                  |           | not null | 
 volume      | integer                  |           | not null | 
 trade_count | integer                  |           | not null | 
 vwap        | numeric                  |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "stock_bar_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("timestamp", symbol, time_scale)
```

ここで、以下のsqlを実行します。

### 実行するSQL

```sql
select * from stock_bar where symbol = 'SPY' and time_scale = '1Min' and "timestamp" >= '2016/01/01'::timestamp order by "timestamp";
```

このSELECT文は成功するのですが、データ量の多さのせいか、実行完了まで12~14秒もかかってしまいます。

### 上記SQLの実行計画

```
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=1046546.40..1181429.25 rows=1156058 width=66)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=1045546.38..1046991.45 rows=578029 width=66)
         Sort Key: "timestamp"
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on stock_bar  (cost=0.00..966517.74 rows=578029 width=66)
               Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (symbol = 'SPY'::bpchar) AND (time_scale = '1Min'::bpchar))
 JIT:
   Functions: 2
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(9 rows)
```

## 疑問

どうすれば、このsql文の実行時間を短くすることができますか？

- 有効なインデックスの貼り方？
- 別のSQL？
- PostgreSQLを止め、別のDBを使う？
- 複合主キーを止める？
- カラム定義を変える？

などの良い解決方法があれば、教えていただけませんか？

※symboやtime_scaleカラムにインデックスを貼ってみたりしたのですが、いまいち時間短縮効果が見られませんでした。

## 実行環境

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

CPU : i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
メモリ : 8G

## 追記

### count(*)の実行結果

#### sql

```
select count(*) from stock_bar where symbol = 'SPY' and time_scale = '1Min' and "timestamp" >= '2016/01/01'::timestamp;
```

こちらのcount(*)の実行にも12~14秒程度の時間がかかる。

※ count(*)実行のため、はじめのsql文にある"order by"の箇所は省いてあるので注意。

#### 上記sqlの実行計画

```
                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=968963.03..968963.04 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=968962.81..968963.02 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=967962.81..967962.82 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on stock_bar  (cost=0.00..966517.74 rows=578029 width=0)
                     Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (symbol = 'SPY'::bpchar) AND (time_scale = '1Min'::bpchar))
 JIT:
   Functions: 6
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(9 rows)
```

Comment: どのように実行されているのでしょうか？ 呼び出し側がクエリ結果を効率よく受信していない可能性はありますでしょうか？ その意味では比較として `select COUNT(*)...` の実行時間も知りたいです。

Comment: @sayuri 情報を追記致しました。実行方法は、ターミナルでpsqlコマンドを叩き、そこからsql文を直入れして実行するのと、dbeaver上からsqlを実行する２つの方法で行っています。なお、実行時間において両者間に大きな違いは認められませんでした。

Comment: 提示された SQL を速くするだけなら、Primary Key の順番を symbol, time_scale, timestamp の順に変えるだけでいい気がします。

Comment: 確認したわけではありませんが流石にそんな簡単な話ではないような気がします。実行計画の表示もクエリの記述順ではなく、インデックスの順に並び変わってますし。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (symbol = 'SPY'::bpchar) AND (time_scale = '1Min'::bpchar))
> ```

と出ています。元の式は `"timestamp" >= '2016/01/01'::timestamp` であり、`'2016/01/01'`をタイムゾーンなしの日時と判断し、各行との比較毎にタイムゾーン変換をしているように見受けられます。

まずはクエリを`'2016/01/01'::timestamp with time zone`に修正して確認してください。

それでもまだ`stock_bar_pk`インデックスが使われないかもしれません。というのも

- 2022/07/27 07:43 JST
- 2022/07/26 22:43 UTC

は表現は異なりますが同じ時刻を指します。では `'2022/07/27'::timestamp without time zone`と比較したらどのような結果が得られるか、を考慮するとインデックスが使えない気がします。

この場合はカラム定義を`timestamp without time zone`に変更し、格納する値をUTCに統一することで改善が見込めるかもしれません。

Comment: クエリを'2016/01/01'::timestamp with time zoneに修正した結果、無事高速に動作しました。しかし高速化したクエリに"order by"(timestampカラムに対して)を付け加えると、動作が遅くなってしまいます。ですのでカラム定義を"timestamp without time zone"に変更して性能を試してみます。